# When I've... I've been

Tags: grammar

Question:

Is it idiomatic to say:

> l'll be speaking English like a native speaker by the time **I've been** in the US for 30 years.
>
> I'll be speaking English like a native speaker **when I've lived** in the US for 30 years.

I don't know why but these sound weird to me, however, I can't think of a different way to put this in a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way to say what you mean would be to flip the statement.

"By the time I've been in the US for 30 years I'll be speaking English like a native speaker."